# Sort 2D array using pointers

Tags: sorting, pointers, multidimensional-array

I have a 2D array int a[8][2].I want to sort the rows using the order given in another array Order[8] = {7,1,0,2,3,6,5,4}.
I tried this,but doesn't work.

```
int result[8][2];
void Rearrange_Vector(int* a,int* order)
{
  int temp;
  int ii =0;
  for ( ii=0;ii<8;ii++)
  {
    temp = *Order;
    result[ii][0]  = *(a + temp*sizeof(int));
    Order++;
  }
```

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

You should interpret the 2D array as a pointer to pointers and swap the row start pointers:

```
#include <algorithm>

int array[8][2];

template<int Rows, int Cols>
void sort(int (&array)[Rows][Cols], int (&order)[Rows]) {
    for (int r = 0; r < Rows; ++r) {
        std::swap_ranges(&array[r][0], &array[r][Cols], &order[r]);
    }
}

int main() {
    int order[8] = {7,1,0,2,3,6,5,4};
    sort(array, order);
    return 0;
}
```

By switching from pointers to arrays as function arguments, you get the additional benefit of the compiler checking if your `order` array has the same number of elements as there are rows in `array`.

Comment: if I do this : result[ii][1] = *(a + temp*sizeof(int) + sizeof(int)), it should actually access the 2nd column of the ith row , am I correct ?

Comment: I don't get your access structure, I adapted my answer which should fit your needs.